# Is it possible to include Babel header line when publishing Org-mode files to HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-publish

Is it possible to include Babel header lines when publishing Org-mode files to HTML with `org-html-publish-to-html`? I would like to have the org-mode keywords exported in addition to the code. Ideally I would like to have a choice of what keywords get published (e.g., `#+NAME:`, `#+BEGIN_SRC`, but not `#+RESULTS`). For a bit of background, I have an org-mode file with multi-language code blocks. I would like to show the results from one code block are input into other code blocks. I see there are [many options](http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html), but apart from "todo", none reference keyword export.

Answer (score 4):

## Try This

I use this method to create code examples to write **How To Use `org-mode`** documentation.

### Wrap Code Blocks within a New `org` Code Block

1. Use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to create empty `org` code block then add `#+NAME:` and  `:exports code` headers to code block.

   ```
   #+NAME: org-code-block-wrapper
   #+begin_src org  :exports code 
   #+end_src
   ```
2. Edit `org` block.

   **Important:** Click inside new `org` code block, add a blank line then use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> to begin editing.

   - Add new code blocks with headers

     e.g.

     ```
     #+NAME: echo-message
     #+HEADER: :var MESSAGE="Hello from Shell Code Block!"
     #+begin_src sh
       echo $MESSAGE
     #+end_src

     #+NAME: display-message
     #+HEADER: :var message="Hello from Ruby Code Block!"
     #+begin_src ruby
       message
     #+end_src
     ```
   - Use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> to return to original buffer.
   - Use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> to save.

When you're done, any `org-mode` syntax will be escaped and ready for export.

```
#+NAME: org-code-block-wrapper
#+begin_src org  :exports code

  ,#+NAME: echo-message
  ,#+HEADER: :var MESSAGE="Hello from Shell Code Block!"
  ,#+begin_src sh
    echo $MESSAGE
  ,#+end_src

  ,#+NAME: display-message
  ,#+HEADER: :var message="Hello from Ruby Code Block!"
  ,#+begin_src ruby
    message
  ,#+end_src

#+end_src
```

When exported, the code blocks with headers should be displayed.

```
#+NAME: echo-message
#+HEADER: :var MESSAGE="Hello from Shell Code Block!"
#+begin_src sh
  echo $MESSAGE
#+end_src

#+NAME: display-message
#+HEADER: :var message="Hello from Ruby Code Block!"
#+begin_src ruby
  message
#+end_src
```

> **Note:** This method should work with most export formats including html. I wrote this answer in an org file then exported the answer as `markdown` to post it to StackExchange.

### How To Extract the Original Blocks from within the `org` Block Wrapper.

- Use add  `#+CALL:` syntax with `:results drawer replace`, then execute statement with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>

  This will put the original blocks inside a `drawer` where they executed with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>.

  ```
  #+CALL: org-code-block-wrapper() :results drawer replace   :exports none 

  #+RESULTS:
  :RESULTS:

  #+NAME: echo-message
  #+HEADER: :var MESSAGE="Hello from Shell Code Block!"
  #+begin_src sh
    echo $MESSAGE
  #+end_src

  #+NAME: display-message
  #+HEADER: :var message="Hello from Ruby Code Block!"
  #+begin_src ruby
    message
  #+end_src
  :END:
  ```

**Code Tested with**

> `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.10.9)`
>   `Org-Mode Version: 8.2.10`

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough, in depth response (+1). At this point, I am wondering if this should simply be an publishing option and if there is a good reason why it is not. I am tempted to alter the org source code to provide the option of exporting keywords. (Maybe easier said than done.)

Comment: @JulienChastang - Thanks! I am always looking for a better way! I'm still learning elisp so I find making changes to the innards of Emacs very challenging.

Comment: "I use this method to create code examples to write How To Use org-mode documentation." -- Please provide links to examples.