# Trouble with Bullets in Emacs Org Mode Code Block when Creating a Draft Wikipedia Page

Tags: org-mode

How can I overcome the issue of asterisks being interpreted as bullets in an Emacs Org Mode code block when creating a draft Wikipedia page?

```
* Draft wikipedia page

#+begin_src Wikipedia

* foo
* bar

#+end_src
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to use a Wikipedia source-code block and try to enter the editing buffer with `C-c '` I get an error: No such language mode: Wikipedia-mode. According to the list of supported languages ([here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html)) there is no wikipedia option.
When I use org code blocks however, and enter the editing buffer with `C-c '`,  type some headings and then close it after editing with `C-c '`, asterisks are prefixed with a comma, like so:

```
* top
  #+begin_src org
    ,* first 
    ,** second
  #+end_src
```

So org-mode does not interpret the asterisks as headlines. Prefixing them with a comma will probably work for your (custom?) Wikipedia source code blocks as well. Or just use org code blocks, edit them with `C-c '` and rename them to Wikipedia after your editing is done.

Comment: More information here:
- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17427/is-it-possible-to-include-babel-header-line-when-publishing-org-mode-files-to-ht/17429#17429
- https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html